# SQL between two dates with range filter

Tags: mysql

I have a problem about an sql with dates. I have two records in my database with the next information:

| id | date_start | date_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-06 |
| 2 | 2021-06-07 | 2021-06-12 |

Im trying to get records between a range of dates.

For example:

- If I put `2021-06-01 - 2021-06-06` in the filter (start and end). It only show ID `1` (exact date)
- If I put `2021-06-03 - 2021-06-15` in the filter (start and end). It only show ID `2` (2021-06-03 is between the ID 2)
- If I put `2021-06-02 - 2021-06-20` in the filter (start and end). Show ID `1` and `2` (because start date is between ID#1 and the full date is between ID#2)

With the first and second thing, none problems. With the 3 form I don't how to do that.

I'm trying:

```
WHERE (date_start >= '$date_start' OR date_end <= '$date_start') 
OR (date_end <= '$date_end' OR date_start >= '$date_end') 


WHERE (date_start >= '$date_start' OR date_end <= '$date_start') 
AND (date_end <= '$date_end' OR date_start >= '$date_end') 


WHERE (date_start >= '$date_start' OR date_end <= '$date_end')
```

I can get the third rule works...

Thanks

Comment: I cannot help myself, I have to mention .. Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: PLease clean up the question a bit. Can you show the answer you want with each query that you actually run. I for one am not totally sure what you are trying to achieve so am not sure what is wrong with what you are doing OR how to make it right

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks about SQLi, but it is just an example how my SQL are formed. And about the second comment, in the three dots I put 3 examples for what I need. Practically is, a filter with date range. The third dot is what i'm fighting to do

For example, in the third dot I put a date range: 2021-06-02 and 2021-06-20, And I have 2 records in my DB, I need to show both records with that input.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 2 rows with the 3rd date range try

```
WHERE start_date between '2021-06-02' AND '2021-06-20'
OR end_date between '2021-06-02' AND '2021-06-20';
```

Comment: _Nope, doesn't work_ Really helpful :) In what way does it not work